# Element of 2D matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have the following Python code to display the matrix element, but it does not show what is expected as I want to show the first element instead of first line elements. What is the problem?

```
import numpy as np

ss = [-0.115, -0.052, 0.559, -0.344, 0.077, 0.032, -0.017, -0.035]
sx = np.matrix([[ss[0],ss[1],ss[2],ss[3]],[ss[4],ss[5],ss[6],ss[7]]])

print('s0=', sx[0])
print('s00=', sx[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing a first row in an 2d array

```
print('s0=', sx[0,:]))  # replace zero with row you want to access
```

And to access first element.

```
print('s00=', sx.item(0,0)) # replace 0,0 with the position of element
```

For documentation [refer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.item.html)